# More inputs in one input field

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to create something similarly to these functionality on picture.
Like stack's TAGS about questions.

[image]

I want to be able to input more records for database in one form input field.

My another solution is to add dinamic field where you get another input field on button add or +, but i would try to implement something like this on picture above.
I googled but i found nothin similary. Any idea how to acomplish that?
I work in php, html, jquery.

Thank you.

Sorry if question is not clear, but i googled and try to find some plugin but i couldn't find anything.
Best regards.

Comment: Make sure question is clear

Comment: https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input this pluging i used

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jquery plugin [Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) to meet your needs.
Make sure that you are passing the data you want to the `select` tag.

```
$('select').select2();
```

While updating you have to update the data to the database.